# Staking with polkadot js api

Tags: polkadot-js, staking, api

I try to make a stake with polkadot js api. Here is my commands:

```js
const info = await api.tx.staking
                    .bond(amount, {Controller: receiver})
                    .paymentInfo(sender); 
const bondTx = api.tx.staking.bond(stenToUnits(amount), {Controller: receiver});
const unsub = await bondTx.signAndSend(senderPair);
await waitUntilFinalized(unsub);
const nominationTx = api.tx.staking.nominate([nominatingValidators[0]]);
await nominationTx.signAndSend(senderPair);`
```

But I get an error:

```
RPC-CORE: submitExtrinsic(extrinsic: Extrinsic): Hash:: 1014: Priority is too low: (3446 vs 2005): The transaction has too low priority to replace another transaction already in the pool.....
index.js:19 Uncaught (in promise) k: 1014: Priority is too low: (3446 vs 2005): The transaction has too low priority to replace another transaction already in the pool.
```

What am I doing wrong? How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The error `Priority is too low: (3446 vs 2005): The transaction has too low priority to replace another transaction already in the pool.` means that there is already a transaction in the queue with that nonce.

You can manually set the nonce in the `signAndSend` method like in this example: [How to use `polkadot-api` to send multiple transactions simultaneously?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/1776/how-to-use-polkadot-api-to-send-multiple-transactions-simultaneously)